# Clojure code evaluation in org-mode produces no output

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, clojure

I am trying to run clojure code from my org file in order to do some literate programming.

**What is not working:**

When I execute the source code block I get `No output produced`.

*Sample src code block*

```
#+begin_src clojure
(+ 2 2)
#+end_src clojure
```

**What is working:**

1. `cider-jack-in` is working and I am able to execute code in the nREPL
2. I am able to execute code from a `.clj` file

Thanks

**Details**

Emacs 25.1 using Spacemacs

Org-Mode 9.0.5

Org babel configuration

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  (require 'ob)
  (require 'ob-clojure)
  (require 'paredit)
  (require 'org-babel-clojure)
  (setq org-babel-clojure-backend 'cider)
  (require 'cider)
  (org-babel-do-load-languages
   'org-babel-load-languages
   '((clojure . t)))
  )
```

Please let me know if you need any other information

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm seeing he same issue. In a little digging, I think I've identified the
problem. However, not sure who this should be reported to.

The problem is in the org-babel-execute:clojure function. This function has the
following bit of code

```
(setq result
       (nrepl-dict-get
    (nrepl-sync-request:eval
     expanded (cider-current-connection) (cider-current-session))
    (if (or (member "output" result-params)
        (member "pp" result-params))
        "out"
      "value")))
```

The problem is in the call to nrepl-sync-request:eval. The documentation states
for this function

> (nrepl-sync-request:eval INPUT CONNECTION &optional NS)
>
> Send the INPUT to the nREPL server synchronously.
>   The request is dispatched via CONNECTION.
>   If NS is non-nil, include it in the request.

Note the last optional argument NS. This is supposed to be a clojure
namespace. However, the org-babel-execute:clojure function is calling this
function with the output from cider-current-session, which returns a unique ID
representing the current session. As a result, the call is returning a data structure with an error and no output (perhaps some error handling is required). The returned result is

```
(dict status (namespace-not-found done error done state state) id 17 session 43e9fd6c-82ed-49fe-9624-0cfc6f56f8b1 changed-namespaces (dict) repl-type cljclj)
```

Note the *namespace-not-found*

Either the argument should be a call to (cider-current-ns) or perhaps it should
just be left out as I don't see how you can pass the namespace as part of the
block evaluation.

EDIT: here is a simple patch which appears to fix the problem. Generated against current head of org git repo

```
---
 lisp/ob-clojure.el | 5 +++--
 1 file changed, 3 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)

diff --git a/lisp/ob-clojure.el b/lisp/ob-clojure.el
index d407105..e542a29 100644
--- a/lisp/ob-clojure.el
+++ b/lisp/ob-clojure.el
@@ -44,6 +44,7 @@

 (declare-function cider-current-connection "ext:cider-client" (&optional type))
 (declare-function cider-current-session "ext:cider-client" ())
+(declare-function cider-current-ns "ext:cider-client" ())
 (declare-function nrepl--merge "ext:nrepl-client" (dict1 dict2))
 (declare-function nrepl-dict-get "ext:nrepl-client" (dict key))
 (declare-function nrepl-dict-put "ext:nrepl-client" (dict key value))
@@ -118,7 +119,7 @@ using the :show-process parameter."
                org-babel-clojure-sync-nrepl-timeout))
               (nrepl-sync-request:eval expanded
                        (cider-current-connection)
-                       (cider-current-session))))
+                       (cider-current-ns))))
           (setq result
             (concat
              (nrepl-dict-get response
@@ -153,7 +154,7 @@ using the :show-process parameter."
        ;; Update the status of the nREPL output session.
        (setq status (nrepl-dict-get response "status")))
          (cider-current-connection)
-         (cider-current-session))
+         (cider-current-ns))

         ;; Wait until the nREPL code finished to be processed.
         (while (not (member "done" status))
-- 
2.7.4
```

Also sent the patch to the emacs-orgmode list

Comment: So are you saying we should edit the function and replace it with `(cider-current-ns)`? And if so, where can I find that function?

Comment: I'm saying that to make ob-clojure work, either the call to (cider-current-session) needs to be dropped or it needs to be replaced with (cider-current-ns). The (cider-current-ns) is part of the cider library (along with cider-current-connection) and (cider-current-session)). Either you need to edit the function or wait until someone updates it upstream, but as it stands now, it does not work. I have reported this on the emacs-org list, but no response yet.

Comment: Your solution is working perfectly. My `ob-clojure` was a bit older so I pulled the newest ones, made the relevant changes and it works! Thank you so much! I wish you had answered a few days before! I would definitely given the bounty to you. :) Thanks!

Comment: As of 3 Jun 2017, Emacs 25.1.1, org 9.0.7, spacemacs 0.200.9, this fix is still not in when I did a fresh clone of spacemacs develop branch and a wipe of my elpa directory. I still needed to purge org directories to get any code-block eval to work `find ~/.emacs.d/elpa/org* -name "*elc" -delete`, then manually apply the patch above. The good news is that the patch works today.

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand the structure of the org git branches and how they relate to the org-plus-contrib package. I know the patch was committed into the main org repository because I did a pull and say the commit. No idea how such patches get into the package files.

Comment: Not sure exactly what has changed here, but the above patch was added to the main org branch on March 7 2017. The maint branch has not had any changes sine 2016 - at least according to the logs. So if you run org from the master branch, all works. Not sure what the elpa packages are built from.

Comment: As of `org-plus-contrib-20170717`, ob-clojure has changed enough that this patch can't be applied automatically--but adding the `(declare-function cider-current-ns "ext:cider-client" ())` at the beginning and string-replacing `cider-current-session` with `cider-current-ns` in `org-babel-execute:clojure` still fixes it.

Comment: Reinstall with the latest version of org mode (org version 20170925 from the "org" archive) fixes the problem without requiring code changes to ob-clojure

Answer (score 0):

You need to have header arguments in the block telling org-babel what you want to include in the results produced - result of evaluation or output to stdout or both. In your case, there is no output that the evaluation of `(+ 1 1)` produces. Try `(println (+ 1 1))`.

```
#+name: Lazy Sequences in Clojure
#+begin_src clojure
 (def a-lazy-sequence (cons 1 (lazy-seq (cons (+1 2) ()))))
#+end_src

#+name: List comprehensions in Clojure
#+begin_src clojure :results output
 (println (str (for [x (range 3)
                     y #{:a :b :c}]
                 [x y])))

#+end_src

#+RESULTS: List comprehensions in Clojure
 : (c l o j u r e . l a n g . L a z y S e q @ e a a 0 1 c e 7)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `(println (+ 1 1))` isn't working. I copy-pasted the code you have above and that does not work either.

Comment: Seems same problem with mine. http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2017-02/msg00429.html

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#+begin_src clojure :results value
(+ 2 2)
#+end_src clojure
```

which prints the returned value instead of output.

Comment: Still does not work, The message area shows "Code block returned no value".

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not necessarily specific to Spacemacs.

While the OP may have implicitly sought a solution *within* Spacemacs, this seems like a good place to mention another alternative (esp. for non-Spacemacs users who are experiencing the same problem after updating some piece of their emacs/org-mode configuration, which is what happened to me).

After trying **many** re-installs of various emacs and org versions, I finally found that [Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org/) (!) and Org 9.0.5 (downloaded as a tar.gz as instructed on http://orgmode.org/) succeeded in getting around the `code block produced no output` problem this poster also experienced.

While Aquamacs may not be a long-term solution for everybody, it certainly can help others who are highly dependent on using org-babel with clojure get around this problem until the above solution is fully recognized and implemented.

The version of emacs used by Aquamacs as of this March 9 2017 is:

`Aquamacs 3.3  GNU Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0, NS appkit-1344.72 Version 10.10.2 (Build 14C109)) of 2016-09-19 on 24a02dbf6b34ae061ef4df89f15bfbc5d3ed497e`